# React Material Ui and react router

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have sidebar and appbar in my app. I want to open a page using Link(react router) which should open up without the appbar and sidebar like a normal html page. Currently it opens inside the body part of sidebar and appbar. Please help.

Comment: I would be nice to at least add some code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly.
**Try it:**

```
// app.js
import React from 'react';
import {Switch, Route, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.css';

import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar';
import AppBar from './components/Appbar';

import Home from './pages/Home';
import Blog from './pages/Blog';

const App = (props) => {

  const pathname = props.location;

  // Just show up with this routes
  const configRoutes = ['/', '/about'];

  const checkPath = configRoutes.includes(pathname);

  return(
    <div className="App">
      {
        checkPath && (<Appbar />
        <Sidebar />)
      }


      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/blog" exact component={Blog} />
      </Switch>

    </div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Comment: Hi John thanks for responding. This will open up both Home and Blog with the sidebar and appbar. I want to open one of them without sidebar and appbar. Thanks